# stack smashing error detected

Tags: c, stack

when i try the following snippet i am getting an error called stack smashing detected. what could be the reason for this potential bug? Can some one explain?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
int glob=88;
int main()
{
    int loc=2;
    pid_t pid=vfork();
    if(pid==0)
    {
        printf("Inside child");
        glob++;
        loc++;
        printf("%d %d" ,glob,loc);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Inside parent");
        glob++;
        loc++;
        printf("%d %d",glob,loc);
    }
}
```

and the output when I run this code is like that

```
user018@sshell ~ $ gcc one.c
user018@sshell ~ $ ./a.out
Inside child89 3Inside parent90 945733057*** stack smashing detected ***: a.out
- terminated
a.out: stack smashing attack in function <unknown> - terminated
KILLED
```

Comment: This is a true StackOverflow question; nice!

Answer (score 1):

From the [Linux man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/vfork.2.html) (and POSIX):

> The vfork() function has the same effect as fork(2), except that the behavior is undefined if the process created by vfork() either modifies any data other than a variable of type  pid_t used  to  store  the  return  value  from  vfork(), or returns from the function in which vfork() was called, or calls any other function before successfully calling _exit(2) or one of the exec(3) family of functions.

You're modifying data and returning from the function in which `vfork` was invoked - both of these lead to undefined behavior. `vfork` is not equivalent to `fork`, the number of things you can do in a `vfork`d child are very, very limited. It should only be used in very specific circumstances, essentially when the only thing you need to do in the child is `exec` something else.

See your operating system's man page for the full details.

Comment: [Here is a pretty good explanation of the problems with `vfork()`](http://ewontfix.com/7/).

Answer (score 1):

`vfork()` is used to create new processes **without** copying the page tables of the parent process. So you can't modify the variables in the child process because they are not there anymore. Use `fork()` instead.

One more thing, it's better to add a `\n` to the end of `printf()` because `stdout` is line buffered by default.

Answer (score 0):

1) I would definitely add a "return 0", since you declared "int main()".

2) If you wanted to disable the warning, use `-fno-stack-protector` in your compile line.

3) If you wanted to debug where the error is coming from, use "-g" in your compile line, and run the program from gdb (instead of running ./a.out).

My closest to "what's wrong" is this man page about vfork():

> http://linux.die.net/man/3/vfork
>
> The vfork() function shall be equivalent to fork(), except that the
>   behavior is undefined if the process created by vfork() either
>   modifies any data other than a variable of type pid_t used to store
>   the return value from vfork(), or returns from the function in which
>   vfork() was called, or calls any other function before successfully
>   calling _exit() or one of the exec family of functions.

For Linux, just use "fork()", and I think you'll be happy :)

Comment: `1)` is not necessary in C99 and above.

Comment: I strongly believe that if you declare a function "int", you should declare a return value.  Anything else is sloppy ... and prone to undefined behavior sooner or later. IMHO...

Comment: Well the C99 and C11 standards define the behavior of main specifically on this point.